# How to evaluate the following integral related to exponential distribution

Tags: integration, integral-transforms

I would like to evaluate the following integral related to the exponential distribution. Let $\delta>1$, and $0<p<1$ and $0<\epsilon<1/\delta$ be reals. We have that

$$
\int_0^{\epsilon p}\exp\left(-x\cdot\tfrac{1}{p}\right)\,\,\mathrm{d}x = p(1-e^{-\epsilon})
$$

I am interested in calculating the related integral

$$
\int_0^{\epsilon p}\exp\left(-x\cdot\tfrac{1-\delta x}{p-\delta x}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x.
$$

I have tried Mathematica to no avail. I would appreciate any help. I would love to hear the reasoning behind the steps if someone has a solution.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you asking for a closed form or an asymptotic?

Comment: A closed form would be great, if one exists. If not, understanding asymptotic behavior would be very helpful.

Comment: Have you tried steepest descent for asymptotics? Also are you interested in asymptotics for large $p$ or $\delta$

Comment: Thanks, I am looking up steepest descent, I have not used it before. I am interested in the behavior as $\epsilon$ gets smaller.

Comment: Mathematica gives the series expansion $p\epsilon+O(\epsilon^2)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. If all the terms depended on $p$, like the first example I mentioned, then it would solve my problem easily. Namely, if the above integral is $pf(\epsilon)$ for some $f$, then we are done. However I am guessing there is a dependence on $\delta$ as well. I wonder if there is a general technique to develop Taylor series for definite integrals.

Comment: @dedekind: look up Watson's lemma.